# Pass data between android application and adobe air application

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have two applications say app1 and app2. App1 is a native android application and App2 is an android application build with adobe air. Now i am able to launch App2 from the App1 using the following intent and also able to pass parameters through URL from App1 to App2

```
        Intent i = Intent.parseUri("App2://arg1=value&secondArgument=someValue", Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        i.setComponent(null);
        startActivity(i);
```

When the App2 is closed i want to send some data  to App1 and go back to App1. So how can i do this in action script?

Could anyone suggest me a method to solve the problem?

Comment: How is app2 closed?  By the user pressing a button in the app?  By the user hitting "back"?  By the user hitting "home"?  By the user closing it with the Android app manager?

Comment: I think you can use a **ServerSocket** bound to localhost on the AIR/AS3 side.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `startActivityForResult` in app 1.

```
Intent i = Intent.parseUri("App2://arg1=value&secondArgument=someValue", Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
i.setComponent(null);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then in the activity in app 2 perform your operation and when complete set the result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra( "key", value );
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

This will trigger the `onActivityResult` in your first app and you can process the intent there:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            id = data.getExtras().getString("key");
        }
    }
}
```

If your second app is an AIR application you will probably need an ANE to handle this, eg through a custom activity.